# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' - JDK issue?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dex

I really don't know why all of a sudden this error has started appearing everytime I try to deploy an app. I wait for an hour and then an error is returned and the app doesn't get deployed. What can be done to resolve this error along with anything related to 'Dex'?

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 3

**My gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "package name"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

In addition, I've noticed these code sections with my **workspace.xml** file, but don't know if they should be removed.

```
          <ExternalTaskPojo>
            <option name="linkedExternalProjectPath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
            <option name="name" value="transformClassesWithDexForDebug" />
          </ExternalTaskPojo>
          <ExternalTaskPojo>
            <option name="linkedExternalProjectPath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
            <option name="name" value="transformClassesWithDexForDebugAndroidTest" />
          </ExternalTaskPojo>
          <ExternalTaskPojo>
            <option name="linkedExternalProjectPath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
            <option name="name" value="transformClassesWithDexForRelease" />
          </ExternalTaskPojo>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try using multidex?

Comment: Can you post more of that stacktrace?

Comment: @JpCrow Does multidex really need to be used?

Comment: @MacaronLover if you have more than 65535 instructions you should use it, and that error may be because of that!

Comment: @JpCrow Still no difference, tried it all!

Comment: @razzledazzle which file are you referring to?

Comment: Some more part of that error meesage

Comment: @razzledazzle I've just posted screenshots of the errror

Comment: Screenshot shows more dependencies than you have set, is this your actual Gradle script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Gradle script, add this:

```
dexOptions {
  javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

"4g" here means 4 GB of your computer's memory. Set it to whatever appropriate based on your computer's specification.